# Database - Using foreign key for multiple row

Tags: database

I am creating a database using several tables.

Basically it's a prototype of a campus' library database which has book and also student information. The program I'm making only has borrow, and return functions for now. So I'm planning to put them this way :

For table STUDENT :

```
 CREATE TABLE STUDENT(
 ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 STUDENT_NAME VARCHAR(30),
 STUDENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 BOOK_ID INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY (BOOK_ID) REFERENCES BOOK(ID)
)
```

And table BOOK :

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK(
 ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 BOOK_TITLE VARCHAR(30),
 BOOK_TOTAL INTEGER NOT NULL,
 BOOK_LEFT INTEGER NOT NULL
)
```

A problem arise when a student is allowed to borrow a maximum of three books. For example book1, book2, and book3. What should I do here?

First would be adding two columns : BOOK_BORROWED, and BOOK_QUOTA in table STUDENT to check their quota, right?

Second, what would be the solution to adding more books borrowed into the student's information? Should I add another table storing the ID(STUDENT), and ID(BOOK) to show their relationship? Or (if possible) use the BOOK_ID column to store multiple ID(BOOK) for example

```
ID 1
STUDENT_NAME Kevin
STUDENT_ID 12345
BOOK_ID 1,2,3 //This?
```

Comment: What does the `STUDENT_ID` column of the `STUDENT` table mean?

Comment: In a university, every student has their own ID, right? At least in my university I have it.. And every uni has their own format, so, for example.. 011 2013 0001. I am a management student (011) of year 2013 (2013) and the first one to register (0001)